# What is the best way to get a single value out of a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset that should have only one value in it, what is the best way to get that single value out and into an integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
// setup sql command and sql connection etc first...
int count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: This is better than using a dataset for what I want to do, nice :)

Answer (score 4):

See a new feature of C# 3.0 'Extension Methods'
You can define your own extension method for any class.
For example:

```
namespace MyEx;

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static object SingleValue(this DataSet ds)
    {
        return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
    }
}
```

After you can use it:

```
using MyEx;

public class Class1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        object value = ds.SingleValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["colname"]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be not to write a single value in a dataset.

but if you cant avoid it:

```
try
{
    //if the value is coming back as string
    int value1 = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
    //if the value is already an integer
    int value2 = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("You do not have even a single value in the DataSet or its not an integer!", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
dt = ds.Tables["TableName"];
Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[rowNumber]["ColumnName"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
int myVar =
 Convert.ToInt32(dsMyDataSet.Tables["MyTable"].Rows[intRowPos]["MyColumn"].Tostring());
```

Comment: There isn't cast from object to decimal or int